# Avoiding re-writing logic twice for server side and client side

Tags: php, javascript, code-reuse

I am writing a piece of software that will allow user to select different options for a product. Prices will vary depending on what options are selected. The server is using a LAMP stack. The client will be using HTML5 and javascript. I am trying to prevent re-writing the validation and price calculations twice, once on the server and then once on the client. I have a couple of options available at this point.

1. Do the normal thing and re-write the validation and price calculations twice
2. Do validation and calculations only on server and use ajax to update the client (slow, I want to avoid.)
3. Implement a secondary language supported by both languages (Lisp comes to mind)
4. Write validation and calculation logic in javascript. Use the V8js library with php
5. Use Node.js

I'm also trying to avoid having to many requirements for the project. If I go the route of Node.js then I will have to install it on a seperate sub domain and then purchase a wildcard SSL certificate, or possibly just another certificate. I'd rather not throw it on the same domain and have some weird proxy/request forwarding program to decide if PHP or Node.js should handle the request.

Some parts of the PHP site will need to access the data. I am using Doctrine 2 as an ORM. Going this route I don't think using Node.JS will be the best route to go.

I'm leaning more towards option one, but maybe I can write some code to produce the required java scriptcode. Are there any other options I'm missing? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry about the late night post! Basically I'm trying to avoid re-writing form validation and price calculation code twice. It would be nice if I can literally use the same code in both places. Then after everything validates and prices are calculated, I can then save and process it on the database side, or if it's the client send over the form and the options they have selected.

The idea is to take the M from MVC and use it both on the server and client. Fo rthe client the models will be filled from the form. the data will from a form. If php, the data will come from JSON.

Comment: Ajax is a good option though you want to avoid it. I do not know about lisp. Then you have time you should do the normal thing. Else i will recommend v8js.

Comment: Can you elaborate on option 3?

Comment: At the time I was thinking about writing a mini language, where input was set from the host to and passed to the interpreted language. The interpreted language would then be ran.

Alternatively, you can write a rule engine. You define constraints/equations as a data structure that can be encoded. Each host language would have to make sure the solver reproduces the same result. The solver shouldn't care where the data comes from. 

To display the results on the client side, you can use a lookup to map results to an element.
Example use cases are showing calculated results, form validations.

Comment: it seems like [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/) and [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) try to solve the problem of duplicated client/server logic. I've never used them though, but Derby in particular looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Will those theoretic "complex" rewrites will worth it? May be it just not worth it.

But if it really so -- then your solution with reusing "backend"-like logic is best. Write it in javascript and reuse in php -- it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the validation routine in Java.

Deliver the code to the client side in an applet - your javascript code can then call the applet's methods.
On the server you can run it as a command line program.

It's a long time since I did any JAVA but I think it's possible to create a single class which could be used as both a command line program and an applet.

The applet doesn't need a UI and can be reduced to 1px square or display:none;